# Missing rss.xml while attempting to bring blogdown (hugo blog) on r-bloggers?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

**Goal:** Bring a blogdown (Hugo) blog on r-bloggers.

There is plenty Information on that topic, suggesting that the rss.xml file has to be modified, see

- [How do I get my blogdown blog on R-Bloggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48997278/how-do-i-get-my-blogdown-blog-on-r-bloggers)
- http://thug-r.life/post/2018-02-07-hugo-to-rbloggers/
- https://gohugo.io/templates/rss/

However, when i create a blog, i am missing that file.

```
> dir.create("blogdown")
> setwd("blogdown/")
> blogdown::new_site()
> list.files(pattern = "rss.xml", recursive = TRUE)
character(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The RSS feed is called `index.xml` instead of `rss.xml`.

```
> list.files(pattern = "[.]xml", recursive = TRUE)
[1] "public/categories/index.xml"      "public/categories/r/index.xml"   
[3] "public/index.xml"                 "public/post/index.xml"           
[5] "public/sitemap.xml"               "public/tags/index.xml"           
[7] "public/tags/plot/index.xml"       "public/tags/r-markdown/index.xml"
[9] "public/tags/regression/index.xml"
```