# blogdown home page not showing toc of posts any more

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I am using blogdown 0.14 with a slightly modified hugo-lithium theme.

It seems that the home page of the blog created has changed.

It used to be a page with the toc of the posts, not it is a page with a link to a page where this toc is displayed.
Is there a way to get back the old behavior?

Comment: You may try to apply the similar fix as https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium/commit/6da5ac2ec7d91ab9bd98a99e9f77a396a469fd94.

Answer (score 1):

That was mentioned an hour ago [on twitter](https://twitter.com/GoHugoIO/status/1162382902937735168):

See [`gohugoio/hugoThemes` issue 682](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugoThemes/issues/682) and [`gohugoio/hugoThemes` issue 678](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugoThemes/issues/678#issue-480803827)

> As stated in [gohugoio/hugo#6153](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/6153), Hugo 0.57.0 has a breaking change since now:
>   (Actually, [0.58.0 will have those changes](https://twitter.com/GoHugoIO/status/1162797325456150528), [0.57.2 has reverted some of those breaking changes](https://gohugo.io/news/0.57.2-relnotes/))
>
> `home.Pages` work like the other sections
>
> Also due to [gohugoio/hugo#6154](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/6154) now:
>
> `.Pages` include the sub sections
>
> The above breaking changes were made for developing new features like Cascading Front Matter and will be also needed in the future.
>
> However during local testing with Hugo 0.57.0 I noticed that plenty of theme demos currently on the showcase use .Data.Pages or just .Pages to render lists (particularly on the index page) and as a result the list pages of these themes now look weird.

The author of the [lithium theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/hugo-lithium-theme/) has been notified.

As [Yihui Xie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui-xie) (Software engineer @rstudio) comments, the [`yihui/hugo-lithium`](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium) fork already illustrates the kind of patch most themes will have to do.
[Commit 6da5ac2](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium/commit/6da5ac2ec7d91ab9bd98a99e9f77a396a469fd94):

The `layouts/_default/list.html` included before:

```
{{ range (where .Data.Pages "Section" "!=" "").GroupByDate "2006" }}
```

Now:

```
{{ $pages := .Pages }}
{{ if .IsHome }}
{{ $pages = .Site.RegularPages }}
{{ end }}
{{ range (where $pages "Section" "!=" "").GroupByDate "2006" }}
```

---

As mentioned in "[Hugo 0.57.2: A couple of Bug Fixes](https://gohugo.io/news/0.57.2-relnotes/)":

> This release reverts the behavior for `.Pages` on the home page to how it behaved in 0.56, but adds a **`WARNING`** telling you what to do to prepare for Hugo 0.58.
>
> In short, `.Page` home will from 0.58 only return its immediate children (sections and regular pages).
>
> In this release it returns `.Site.RegularPages`.
>   So to prepare for Hugo 0.58 you can either use `.Site.RegularPages` in your home template, or if you have a general `list.html` or RSS template, you can do something like this:
>
> ```
> {{- $pctx := . -}}
> {{- if .IsHome -}}{{ $pctx = .Site }}{{- end -}}
> {{- $pages := $pctx.RegularPages -}}
> ```