# Blogdown RSS feed not working when I submit to Rbloggers. Old solution no longer works

Tags: r, blogdown

I generated my blog using blogdown but when I have tried to submit it to R-Bloggers it is not accepted because my feed returns the following error:

`This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters.`

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48997278/how-do-i-get-my-blogdown-blog-on-r-bloggers) the older solution no longer works as of Hugo v0.58.2. I'm using Hugo 0.72.0.