# Get blogdown on r-blogggers for hugo-goa

Tags: r, blogdown

I attempt to bring the following blog style `blogdown::new_site(theme = "shenoybr/hugo-goa")` to r-bloggers.

Following [How do I get my blogdown blog on R-Bloggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48997278/how-do-i-get-my-blogdown-blog-on-r-bloggers) seems to be outdated.

A new solution appeared: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63499033/8538074, which i attempted to follow.

```
dir.create("blog18")
setwd("blog18")
blogdown::new_site(theme = "shenoybr/hugo-goa")
```

Then follow the answer linked above:

```
dir.create(path = "layouts/tags")
xx = readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liao961120/Hugo-RSS/master/layouts/categories/rss.xml")
writeLines(text = xx, con = "layouts/tags/rss.xml")
blogdown::build_site()
```

**Push to github:**

```
go to github and create repo
{GITHUBUSERNAME}.github.io
```

for me it is TyGu1.github.io

Drag and drop all files in github upload

**Check Website:**

go to https://tygu1.github.io/
--> Website is up

As suggested in https://www.r-bloggers.com/add-your-blog/
go to

```
paste0("https://simplepie.org/demo/?feed=", URLencode("https://tygu1.github.io/", reserved = TRUE))
"https://simplepie.org/demo/?feed=https%3A%2F%2Ftygu1.github.io%2F"
```

RSS feed does not work.

**Question:**

Which steps do i have to Change for the rss feed to be valid (using the shenoybr/hugo-goa style)

**Edit:**

As asked/suggested in the question: Github pages seems to activated already:
(In other repos i see "GitHub Pages is currently disabled. ", therefore i assume it is activated in the current repo, see the picture below).

[image]

Comment: I think you need a Github page (`gh-page` branch). Try to activate it in the settings of your repo.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thank you for your comment. I made an edit, it seems that gh-pages is already activated right?

Comment: Yes. It is more usual to use the name `gh-pages` for this branch. Your feed is [here](https://tygu1.github.io/blog/index.xml). And it works : [https://simplepie.org/demo/?feed=https%3A%2F%2Ftygu1.github.io%2Fblog%2Findex.xml](https://simplepie.org/demo/?feed=https%3A%2F%2Ftygu1.github.io%2Fblog%2Findex.xml). So the problem is that `/blog` is missing in your link.

Answer (score 2):

The address of your website is correct but the one of your blog is https://tygu1.github.io/blog.

The XML feed is located at https://tygu1.github.io/blog/index.xml. If you paste it in **simplepie.org**, it works: https://simplepie.org/demo/?feed=https%3A%2F%2Ftygu1.github.io%2Fblog%2Findex.xml.

So the problem was the missing **/blog**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I confirm, the feed is showing now. (+1) I realise i was unprecise with my question. R-Bloggers requires the full feed, not a summary. But this was my error, since it was not clear from the question. Should i open a new one for that?

Comment: If the actual problem is the full RSS feed and https://stackoverflow.com/a/49080861/559676 no longer works, you may comment there.

Comment: Hi Yihui, thanks for taking the time! I confirm the actual Problem is the full rss feed and the linked answer does not work for me. My sample site "tygu1.github.io" is now modified, but i am happy to build any Kind of reproducible examples that might help!